# In the Key of C major what would an F# major chord be?

Tags: theory, analysis, roman-numerals, functional-harmony

Roman Numeral Analysis 
G   F#    F   all major chords

Comment: Is the F# just a short, passing chord between the G and the F?

Comment: Basically, and honestly I'd just call it a V-#IV-IV. Wikepedia calls it a Chromatic Passing chord. I see lead sheets but know figured bass for that chord.

Comment: G=V; F#=#IV, F=IV, assuming key C. That works for me, and is clear. Suppose it could be V/VII but why bother?

Comment: I know right. Or you could say your borrowing the C lydian mode the IV which would be F#major. I know in lydian mode The VII is minor, beautiful mode.

Answer (score 3):

V, #IV, IV.   Or maybe neater as V, bV, IV.   Chromatic runs often use flats coming down, sharps going up.    I don't think you need to look for functional significance in this bit of 'planing'.

Answer (score 1):

**Roman numerals have a functional meaning**. As such, `#IV` and `bV`, while literally accurate, "don't exist" in Roman numeral (functional) analysis. They would be given other numerals based on their functional role.

In C major, given no other context, **`G F# F` would be interpreted as `G Gb F`**, because while `F#` has no functional role in `C major` (or `F major` or `G major`), `Gb` does have a roll in `F major`, the target of the progression: it's the `bII` or "Neapolitan" chord, whose job it is to resolve down by half step.

#### Interpretation #1

- Thinking in terms of `F`, the `IV` chord in `C major`, the Roman numeral analysis would be `V bII/IV IV`.

#### Interpretation #2

- However, in functional analysis (Roman numeral analysis), moving from `V` to `IV` is unusual at best. Instead, an interpretation in `G major` (the `V` chord in `C major`) could be considered: `V bII/bVII/V bVII/V`.